# shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier always executed first

Tags: objective-c, queue, addsubview

I have a function called "openButtonPressed" which gets executed when a button on the ui gets pressed. Now I would like to show a loading view at first and then execute the segue. For some reason, the segue always gets called first.
Does somebody have a clue?

Thank you!

```
- (void)openButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSDebug(@"Open Button");
    [self showLoadingView];
    static NSString* segueToContinue = kSegueToContinue;

    if ([self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:segueToContinue sender:self]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueToContinue sender:self];
    }
}
```

```
- (void)showLoadingView
{
    if(!self.loadingView) {
        self.loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
    }
    [self.loadingView show];
}
```

Comment: Checkout is this segue is performed in storyboard. And you perform it twice at code.

Comment: I just checked and no its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hints below were very helpful to me and totally a better solution but I ended up using **[CATransaction flush];** to force the refresh.

```
- (void)openButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSDebug(@"Open Button");
    [self showLoadingView];
    [CATransaction flush];
    static NSString* segueToContinue = kSegueToContinue;
    if ([self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:segueToContinue sender:self]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueToContinue sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LoadingView is being initialized without a size.
It also may be executing the segue very quickly and you don't have any time to see the loading view.

You can set a breakpoint at the performSegue call and use the view debugger in Xcode to confirm if the view was loaded and what size the view was initialized to.

Comment: Yes the strange part is that when I set a breakpoint at the performSegue call, this breakpoint gets called before the loading view appears. When I comment out the whole if, the loading view appears immediately. The question now is, how can I force the loading view to appear before?
[Here is an image of the altered code i mentioned](https://ibb.co/SNfRmQz)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the view is not in the right place or in the right size. But even if you fix that you need to add a delay so the user can see the loading... I replicated your scenario here and after giving the view a initWithFrame it appears, but cannot be seen because is too fast...

If you want to show the loading for a period of time before the performSegue, you could use the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`.

If you need to wait an action from the loadingView, create a completionHandler in the loadingView initializer...

Comment: Thank you very much, your hint was very helpful!